# How to handle tcp inputstream correctly - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, tcp, inputstream

I'm creating an android application that needs a permanent TCP-Connection to a Server.

I've created a Service that establishes the Connection and listens for incoming Bytes on the Inputstream (The service runs in the background).

```
public  class TCPServiceConnection extends Service{
        //variables......
        //...............
        public void onCreate() { 
               establishTCPConnection(): 
        }
```

The first 4 incoming bytes symbolize the message-length of a complete Message.

After reading a complete Message from the Inputstream into a separate buffer, I want to call another Service/Asynctask in a separate Thread that analyses the Message. (The service should continue listening for further incoming messages).

```
        public handleTCPInput() {
               while(tcp_socket.isConnected()) {
               byte[] buffer = readCompletemessagefromTCPInputstream; 
               calltoAnotherThreadToanalyzeReceivedMessage(buffer); 
               }
               //handle exceptions.......
        }
```

Is there an existing Messagequeue-system in Android/Java that already handles the multi-access onto my separated byte[] buffer ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'multi-access onto my separated byte[] buffer'?

Comment: Isn't the byte[] buffer in my "handleTCPInput" method passed by reference to the other thread ?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm really new in the Java-programming world and until now I thought that methods are always called by reference in java ?

Comment: Sidenote: `tcp_socket.isConnected()` most probably does not exactly do what you expect it to do. But to your question. In Java, all Method parameters are passed by value. In your case, a copy of the "address" of the buffer is passed. So if you change something inside the array, it will be seen at the caller, but you cannot assign another array instance to the parameter in the called method and have it changed at the caller also. So if you'd do `buffer = new byte[128]` inside `calltoAnother...` it would not affect the contents of the variable `buffer`in `handleTCPInput`

Comment: Spoiler: `isConnected` will turn true and **stay true** if the connection has been successfully established. When it is lost, the only way to tell is when an I/O Operation fails. And even then you could have a slow server causing a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this I suggest you start a handler thread which will continuously read from the input stream.

As soon it has read the incoming message, it passes it to main thread using handler.

For eg. handler.sendMessage()

Now since this processing is not a heavy operation you can decide main/UI thread to process this information or you can start a async task to do it.